# Training Neural Networks with Gym

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have some issue with code provided below.
I am working on python 3.6.
I already reinstalled Python and all modules required to run the code.
In general I did everything based on this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/openai-cartpole-neural-network-example-machine-learning-tutorial/).

## Issue description:

When I run this code I am getting the following warnings and no output at all.
I do not understand what these warnings mean and how I can fix it.
I will be grateful for any help.

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "D:\Users\Rafal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site
>   packages\h5py__init__.py", line 36
>       from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from
>   float to np.floating is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as
>   np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type

And:

> [33mWARN: gym.spaces.Box autodetected dtype as . Please provide explicit dtype.[0m

Code ran by me:

```
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from statistics import median, mean
from collections import Counter

LR = 1e-3
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
env.reset()
goal_steps = 500
score_requirement = 50
initial_games = 10000


def initial_population():
    # [OBS, MOVES]
    training_data = []
    # all scores:
    scores = []
    # just the scores that met our threshold:
    accepted_scores = []
    # iterate through however many games we want:
    for _ in range(initial_games):
        score = 0
        # moves specifically from this environment:
        game_memory = []
        # previous observation that we saw
        prev_observation = []
        # for each frame in 200
        for _ in range(goal_steps):
            # choose random action (0 or 1)
            action = random.randrange(0,2)
            # do it!
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

            # notice that the observation is returned FROM the action
            # so we'll store the previous observation here, pairing
            # the prev observation to the action we'll take.
            if len(prev_observation) > 0 :
                game_memory.append([prev_observation, action])
            prev_observation = observation
            score+=reward
            if done: break

        # IF our score is higher than our threshold, we'd like to save
        # every move we made
        # NOTE the reinforcement methodology here. 
        # all we're doing is reinforcing the score, we're not trying 
        # to influence the machine in any way as to HOW that score is 
        # reached.
        if score >= score_requirement:
            accepted_scores.append(score)
            for data in game_memory:
                # convert to one-hot (this is the output layer for our neural network)
                if data[1] == 1:
                    output = [0,1]
                elif data[1] == 0:
                    output = [1,0]

                # saving our training data
                training_data.append([data[0], output])

        # reset env to play again
        env.reset()
        # save overall scores
        scores.append(score)

    # just in case you wanted to reference later
    training_data_save = np.array(training_data)
    np.save('saved.npy',training_data_save)

    # some stats here, to further illustrate the neural network magic!
    print('Average accepted score:',mean(accepted_scores))
    print('Median score for accepted scores:',median(accepted_scores))
    print(Counter(accepted_scores))

    return training_data
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer the second concern with this error:

```
gym.spaces.Box autodetected dtype as <class 'numpy.float32'>
```

Go to the directory of the downloaded "gym" file. Go into gym/spaces/ and open up the "box.py" file.
Somewhere around the 12th line, you should see:

```
def __init__(self,low.shape=None,high.shape=None,shape=None,dtype=None):
```

Change the `dtype=None` to `dtype=np.float32`

This fixed the error for me.

Comment: First of all I reinstalled my system because I had other unusual issues with GYM.
After this I used your solution and it helped thanks a lot.